# Numerical method for a free boundary problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, finite-differences

I am consider the following free boundary problem: $u_t + \mathcal{L}u = 0,  0<x<s(t)$, with the boundary conditions: $u(T,x) = f_T(x)$, $u(t,s(t)) = g(t)$ and $u_x(t,s(t))=C$. Here, $\mathcal{L}$ is a linear differential operator.

I am planning to use the finite difference scheme to solve the problem. However, how should I update the free boundary when using FD? Any reference will be appreciated.

Comment: From a physical point of view, you seem to fix temperature and heat current over the boundary indepenedently, that's not a possible experimental setting. Mathematically the problem is well posed for a linear combination of boundary value and slope mimicking the  temperature of the environment and an insulating layer, reducing the immediate update at the moving boundary by a current proportional to the slope over the boundary skin. The open  question: At what temperature and what density the heat carrying medium enters or leaves  over the moving boundary? Example: melting ice mountain.

Comment: is there is condition on $s(t)$?  Usually a problem like stefan needs to add know the interface's dynamics.

Comment: You can solve boundary problems using front tracking or fixed domain approach, of which the latter can be more flexible. Take a look at this textbook (https://global.oup.com/academic/product/free-and-moving-boundary-problems-9780198533702) which gives a nice introduction of numerical methods for solving free boundary problems . Also this paper (https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377042723002169) gives a nice overview of some existing methods, and an interesting way to handle the difficulties introduced by the existence of free boundary when solving with FD.